# Bootstrap Popover placement not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am having trouble with getting the Twitter Bootstrap Popover placement option to work properly. Here is my code for my button, I added **data-placement="bottom"** into the code as you can see. also a live preview here: http://www.japaneselanguagefriend.com/application/popover.php

```
<a href="#" id="blob" class="btn btn-primary" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom"　data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" data-original-title="A title">hover for popover</a>
```

[image]

[image]

It keeps displaying the popover directly over my button, and it is not even writing the correct title or content to the popover.
Here is my footer with the **source scripts**

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.jigowatt.js"></script>





<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
       $(function () {
            $("#blob")
        .popover({
            offset: 0
         })
       })
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: try $("#blob").tooltip() in document.ready

Comment: Thanks but for some reason that just displays a tooptip inside of the popover now. Really strange! thanks though :(

Comment: Couple errors on that page you shared: 1) jQuery is getting loaded twice; 2) the `<script>` tag for your function call isn't closed properly. Otherwise, works for me: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/s8Bzp/). But that's not loading all those additional scripts.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle? Your link doesn't work.